# Angular i18next empty translation?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, i18next

Is it possible to set up Angular's i18next provider so that it wouldn't show any value when the value for the key is not defined.

The problem is that if for instance  for the key `my:key`I don't have any translation defined. I would like to show only empty string istead of `my:key` in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off all fallbacks in service configuration:

```
$i18nextProvider.options = {
    fallbackOnNull: false,
    fallbackOnEmpty: false,
    fallbackLng: false
};
```

(fallbackLng is optional, I did not really take what you need).